# Is there a way to hide malicious google results in Mac?

Tags: google

When I googled, some links were marked by Google as malicious that can harm my computer. Since I don't want to mis-click any of those, I would like to know whether there are any configs that just simply hide those links? Or stop Google from returning those links in the first place?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm unaware of any way to directly implement the hiding of search results in Google itself. However, the app [Dr.Antivirus](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dr-antivirus-remove-malware/id1068435535?mt=12) along with a few others offer a feature where websites are deemed safe or unsafe and a marker will appear next to each search result allowing you to quickly see if it is safe or not even before you have clicked any results.

Answer (score 1):

The Safari web browser has extensions you can load that will warn you about dangerous websites. The one I use is called **URL Advisor**. Another one is **SafeSurf**. If you go to "Safari Extensions" under the Safari menu item you can get a list of available extensions.

I don't know for sure about Google Chrome or Firefox but if extensions exist for Safari I feel confident they exist for other browsers as well.